# Manually restarting d3 drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use 2 separate drag behaviours depending on whether a node was held for over a second, or just dragged immediately.  I'm identifying the hold behaviour easily enough by using a timer with mouseup and mousedown and storing it in a "nodeHeld" variable.  But then I run into issues applying that to the drag...

If I use "d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();" on my dragstart, then it enables a single node to be dragged on it's own.  If I omit the stopPropagation line, then the other drag listener (on the canvas) ensures that all nodes are dragged even though I'm clicking on one specifically.  But what I wanted to do was use my "nodeHeld" variable to determine whether or not to drag all nodes, or a specific one...

```
var drag = force.stop().drag()
                    .on("drag", function(d) { 
                        if (nodeHeld) { 
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); 
                            //this doesn't seem to do anything unless it's included at dragstart
                        }   
                    })
                    .on("dragstart", function(d) {
                        //d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); 
                        //With the above commented out, a drag on a node drags all nodes
                        //I can't use the "nodeHeld" check here either, because it takes 
                        //a second or so to become "true" (by which point the drag has started)
                    });
```

As I describe in the comments above, it seems like stopPropagation will only work on dragstart (which is too early for me to say whether the node has been held or not).

So I'm really hoping there's a way for me to restart the drag behaviour after I've calculated a node being held, so that I can add my "if (nodeHeld) ..." check to dragstart.

Thanks for any thoughts at all!

Comment: Any ideas at all?  Happy to post other sections of the code if you think it would help.  Thanks.

Comment: P.s. If I use a timer in dragstart (to ensure nodeHeld is calculated), then I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined"...

.on("dragstart", function(d) { 
           setTimeout(function () {
            if (nodeHeld) {
             d3Event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); 
                   }
        }, 1200);
          })

And if I try stashing d3Event.sourceEvent in a variable before the timer function, and then referring to myVariable.stopPropagation() in the timer, then nothing at all happens (just like if I use stopPropagation in the "drag" behaviour).